If $f$ is modular for $\Gamma_0(4)$ with certain coefficients vanishing, then $U_4(f)$ is modular for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$
Let $f(\tau)=\sum_{n\geq0}a(n)q^n$, $(q=e^{2\pi i \tau})$ be a modular form of weight $k$ on the group $\Gamma_0(4)$ with $a(n)=0$ for $n\equiv2\mod 4$. Then how to prove that $U_4f(\tau)$ is modular weight $k$ for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, where $U_df(\tau):=\sum_{n\geq 0}a(dn)q^n$?
I tried using that $U_4f(\tau)=U_2f(\tau/2)$ where $U_2f$ is modular for $\Gamma_0(2)$ by Cohen-Stromberg Modular Forms (Proposition 13.2.5) and that if $\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}), \gamma'=\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b/2 \\
    2c & d 
\end{pmatrix}$, then $(\gamma\tau)/2=\gamma'(\tau/2)$. The problem is that $b/2$ is not necessarily in $\mathbb{Z}$, so we can't use modularity with respect to $\gamma'$ to verify that $U_4f$ is weight $k$ $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-invariant.
Since $U_4f$ is clearly invariant under $T=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ it would also suffice to show invariance under the other generator of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, $S=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$, but I wasn't able to do that either. Do I need some other intermediate result to make my proof work, or is another method the way to go?

You should add what you tried, your question will be received better

@Zima Thanks, I've added my attempt now

This question is actually not as easy as it looks!
Consider the form $g = U_2 f$. Then $a_n(g) = a_{2n}(f)$, so the condition on $f$ translates to the claim that $a_n(g) = 0$ for all odd $n$. Moreover, $g$ is modular for $\Gamma_0(2)$ as you observe in the question.
So let's set $h(z) = g(z / 2)$. I claim this is actually a modular form of level 1; this clearly solves the problem, since obviously $h(z) = U_2(g) = U_4(f)$.
By construction $h$ is preserved by the subgroup $$\Gamma^0(2) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} : 2 \mid b\right\}.$$
But since it can be written as a power series in $q = e^{2\pi i z}$, it's also preserved by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. This isn't in $\Gamma^0(2)$, and $\Gamma^0(2)$ has index 3 which is prime; so the subgroup generated by it and $\Gamma^0(2)$ together must be all of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
